# How do I ignore stuck threads in a Weblogic Server

Tags: multithreading, weblogic, commonj

I've got the below code working on Weblogic Application Server 10.3.2. The long running task executed on timerExpired takes longer than the server wide StuckThreadMaxTime of 600 seconds. I do not want to modify this value, but just to ignore the stuck thread timeout for this particular thread of processing.

I can see how this can be accomplished using a commonj WorkManager from this:
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11035_01/wls100/config_wls/self_tuned.html#wp1069945

And then by adding the following to the work-manager tag in the weblogic.xml file:

> `<ignore-stuck-threads>true</ignore-stuck-threads>`

But how on earth do I do the same for a Timer/TimerManager?

web.xml

```
<resource-ref>
 <res-ref-name>tm/TestTimer</res-ref-name>
 <res-type>commonj.timers.TimerManager</res-type>
 <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
 <res-sharing-scope>Unshareable</res-sharing-scope>
</resource-ref>
```

TestTimer.java:

```
import commonj.timers.Timer;
import commonj.timers.TimerListener;
import commonj.timers.TimerManager;

public class TestTimer implements TimerListener {
    public void init() 
       TimerManager timerManager =    
          (TimerManager)initContext.lookup("java:comp/env/tm/TestTimer");
       timerManager.schedule(this, SCHEDULE_DELAY);                             

    }

    @Override
    public void timerExpired(Timer timer) {
        // perform long-running task    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took the easy way out (time pressures) by doing the processing in work scheduled by a WorkManager when the timer expires.

```
public MyClass implements TimerListener, Work
    @Override
    public void timerExpired(Timer timer) throws Exception {    
        WorkManager workManager = initContext.lookup("wm/myworkmanager");
        workManager.schedule(this);                 
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        doWork();
    }
}
```

web.xml

```
<resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>wm/myworkmanager</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>commonj.work.WorkManager</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    <res-sharing-scope>Unshareable</res-sharing-scope>
</resource-ref>
```

weblogic.xml

```
<wls:work-manager>
    <wls:name>wm/myworkmanager</wls:name>        
    <wls:ignore-stuck-threads>true</wls:ignore-stuck-threads>
</wls:work-manager>
```

Answer (score 0):

I havent tried this, but adding this entry in weblogic.xml should work

```
<work-manager>
       <name>timer/TestTimer</name>
       <ignore-stuck-threads>true</ignore-stuck-threads>
    </work-manager>
```

The `name` matches `res-ref-name` in web.xml

My server started up with the Timer okay, I havent tested your client to see if the stuck thread messages are ignored

Comment: Hi. I tried this, didn't seem to work, so instead I'm now scheduling WorkManager work when the timer expires with the work manager config set to ignore stuck threads.