# weblogic timeout due to long DB query

Tags: java, weblogic, apache-poi, weblogic12c

My requirement is that I read records from an excel sheet (containing 3 columns) and check whether the record exists in the db. If it exists, I write them along with some more data (2 more columns of excel) into a separate db table. Worst case is 10000 records. The problem I am facing is that weblogic times out after reading just 50 records. My current code logic is:

```
validate method(){

    callValidatemethod 1()----- checks whether the first column data exists in the db. This happens for each record. worst case 10000 records

    callValidatemethod 2()----- checks whether the second column data exists in the db. This happens for each record. worst case 10000 records

    callValidatemethod 3()----- checks whether the third column data exists in the db. This happens for each record. worst case 10000 records

    if(validation returns true){

        writing the valid data to arraylist
        call writeData method---which writes the arraylist to the db.

}
```

The ui page gives network error -server to slow or too busy. But in the back end the code runs just fine since on the console the code prints SOP statements. I have made changes in weblogic jta settings giving them the Max timeout values. But still.
Is there a better logic than this.

Comment: Long running queries to the db write in the separate thread and don't clash the main DT.

Comment: What sort of app are you using to do this? A .war/.ear? Threaded? Look into work managers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7735575/how-do-i-ignore-stuck-threads-in-a-weblogic-server

Comment: Weblogic should not time-out based on the information you give. Can you specify the scenario in more detail?